# Using FileSyncProvider COM with side-by-side and registration-free deployment and execution

Tags: c#, .net, com

I am trying to do the following :
 - follow the step by step guide http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973913.aspx to do registration-free of com component (on locked-down computer for example)
 - in order to use Microsoft Sync Framework 2.1 with side-by-side deployment registration-free com (visual studio 2010 , c#.net 4.0 , windows 7 and xp ), because i would avoid installing the client runtime msi on every computer (only 2 or 3 users will use the application)

is this possible ?
if so, what is the manisfest content, especially for tlbid and iid values ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Set the Isolated property of the interop assembly to True and the manifest is generated automatically.  Not so sure this will come to a good end, that looks like a pretty heavy api.  You also can't avoid having to install the redistributable on those machines so there's not much point to it in general.